# How to use querySelectorAll only for elements that have a specific child element?

Tags: javascript, dom

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Column name</th>
        <th>Column name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column value</td>
        <td>Column value</td>
      <tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Column name</th>
        <th>Column name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Column value</td>
        <td>Column value</td>
      <tr>
    </table>
```

I'd like to process all `tr` that contain a `td`, but can only find contain queries for attributes and content; not elements. Is the latter possible with a single query?

Comment: Only with [`:has`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:has), which isn’t supported in any browser yet. Use a `.filter` on the result, or match the descendants, then `.map` with a `.closest` selector, then apply `new Set`.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("tr > td")` Is this what you want...

Comment: @decpk That selects the `<td>`s, not the `<tr>`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you can use `filter` to get the appropriate rows

```js
const rowsWithTd = [...document.querySelectorAll("table tr")].filter( x => x.querySelector("td"))
console.log(rowsWithTd.map(x => x.outerHTML))
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column value</td>
  <tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Column name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column value</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```